# Is it bad practice to chain Kotlin null safety operator when dealing with immutable variables and properties?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Take the hypothetical pseudo-code below as an example:

```
val a: Any? = ...
a?.takeIf { ... }
    ?.apply { ... }
    ?.let { ... }
```

I've read an article recently that suggested this kind of usage of the null safety operator creates redundant null checks when compiled into Java machine code. Here -- according to that article -- it would seem that when this is compiled, when `a != null` evaluates to `true` it will essentially check if `a != null` three times on the same variable. It might make since when you are dealing with a `var` property that has the potential to change values between checks. But in situations with immutable `val` properties, this creates redundant checks. If the above example is executed on each element over an enumerable data structure, this will scale the redundant checks linearly, making the end result 3 times more computationally complex than it needs to be.

Syntactically it makes a lot of sense to use Kotlin in this way. But if it produces wasteful/redundant checks like this, it seems like this is better to avoid this by explicitly null checking the variable with an `if` statement.

Is it appropriate to chain usages of null safety operator, especially when combined with lambdas that would check the same immutable variable multiple times? Or in other words, will doing so really result in excessive/redundant null checks in compiled java machine code?

Comment: Performance-wise, it is going to be inconsequential in the vast majority of cases. Maybe it was in a loop of 10,000 items, you might start worrying about that level of optimization. What you should be far more concerned with is code clarity. This level of chaining, not for providing a default but for doing a series of actions, is ugly and hard to follow. In the example above, the `?.` is unnecessary before `takeIf`, and whatever code is in `apply` could be put in the `let` statement.

Comment: There really isn't such a thing as excessive null checks.  The JIT will eliminate any that are provably unnecessary at runtime.  This is not worth being concerned about.

Comment: @Tenfour04 good point, though the code was meant more as a hypothetical situation rather than a realistic example. I guess the concern is that you might not always know the size of an enumerable you are looping over in order to know to optimize for that case. Though will probably have bigger optimization issues than just some null checks at that point.